# Which remote desktop protocol offers the smallest attack surface?

Tags: linux, remote-desktop

I am trying to "outsource" potentially dangerous applications such as web browsing to a separate Linux machine sitting in its own network segment and which is isolated by a rigorous network firewall from our internal network, thus I am trying to build a "remote-controlled browser". Since I am in the early planning phase, I wonder which remote protocol to choose best for remote access to such a machine. I have to deal with a potentially malicious server and I want to protect the client (Windows or Linux) which accesses it.

Which remote control protocol would you recommend for a small attack surface? I can think at the moment of

- RDP
- VNC
- SPICE (from the proxmox hypervisor)
- NX (Nomachine)
- X2GO
- XPRA via HTML5

It is clear that the more lightweight a protocol is, the more suitable it is. However, I would prefer to be able to also stream video + audio over it (which might rule out some protocols).

Comment: I question your initial premise. Your threat model is to protect your network from a compromised browser. In that case, use a VM. You can limit the traffic to just the outside world. And you don't have resource problems and it's far cheaper and easier to implement.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. This is exactly what I am trying to do. The VM with the web browser would run on a proxmox hypervisor in a separate network segment. However, I would like to access the VM conveniently from my usual desktop. Now I wonder which is the best way to do that.

Comment: But why a separate machine? You have not stated a reason for that.

Comment: The question also doesn't appear to be security related. You want a remote protocol, but you have only stated a resource requirement. Any remote protocol that can stream the way you want would appear to satisfy what you've asked. Is there a security angle here?

Comment: @schroeder Because I trust a proper openBSD / pfsense more than my desktop os to separate.

And yes, the question is security related: I wonder which protocol offers the smallest attack surface.

Answer (score 0):

You're asking a question about protocol security, but it's not entirely clear how you would compare these as they aren't exactly equal. You're also not considering the supply chain security of the software that will speak these protocols. It hardly matters if VNC were the most secure protocol if you're running a 20 year old VNC server that's never been audited and is full of buffer overflows on your linux machine.

Additionally I don't think you have put sufficient effort into the threat modelling. If someone compromises your browsing machine and hooks the SSL traffic, they will still be able to see all your private data, usernames and passwords. Which might allow them to chain further attacks against your internal network infrastructure.

Additionally the browsing machine is likely situated behind a SOHO grade router which are notoriously vulnerable. If the same router is shared between the networks then the attacker could affect one network from the other by say, changing the DNS settings.

IMHO you should decide what you want to protect against, how you will remain secure if the browser server gets compromised and then consider the holistic view of remote management, including supply chain, not just a popularity contest of protocols based on people's gutfeel/opinion.

Comment: Thanks for that extensive comment. The threat model is a malicious internet site I am browsing to. For sure this virutalized web browser is not used for everything. It is just used for browsing the internet in any unauthenticated way e.g. wikipedia, google searches, watching youtube videos etc. I would like protect my main machine from drive-by downloads or more generally any infections possible via web browsing.

It is obvious that an outdated software version poses risks. However, my question intends to put light on which protocol to choose to give such bugs as least room as possible!